# Representation of Transformations by Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a problem as follows:

Let $T$ be the linear transformation from $R^3$ into $R^2$ defined by $$T(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1 + x_2, 2x_3 - x_1).$$

If $\mathfrak{B} = \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3\}$ and $\mathfrak{B'} = \{\beta_1, \beta_2\},$ where $\alpha_1 = (1, 0, -1), \alpha_2 = (1, 1, 1), \alpha_3 = (1, 0, 0), \beta_1 = (0, 1), \beta_2 = (1, 0)$
What is the matrix of $T$ relative to the pair $\mathfrak{B}, \mathfrak{B'}$?

So, I have:

$T(\alpha_1) = T(1, 0, -1) = (1, -3) = -3 \beta_1 + 1 \beta_2$.

$T(\alpha_2) = T(1, 1, 1) = (2, 1) = 1 \beta_1 + 2 \beta_2$.

$T(\alpha_3) = T(1, 0, 0) = (1, -1) = -1 \beta_1 + 1 \beta_2$.

This leads to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. But this does not look right because when I perform the matrix multiplication $[T_\alpha]_\mathfrak{B'} \neq A[\alpha]_\mathfrak{B}.$ What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Actually they are equal. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the notation you are using. I am gonna give a try to give a hint anyway.

The matrix corresponding to $T(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1+x_2,2x_3-x_1)$ is given by

$${\bf M_T} = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1&1&0\\
-1&0&2
\end{array}\right]$$

assuming we multiply this matrix to the right with the vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$, because then we get the column vector $(x_1+x_2,2x_3-x_1)^T$

---

**Hint:**
A base change matrix can be written:
$${\bf B} = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}1&0&-1\\1&1&1\\1&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

Maybe now it gets easier?

Comment: Your answer is based on the standard basis of $R^3$. But the problem is not relative to the standard basis.

Comment: Yes, I added a base change matrix. What would be reasonable operations to use involving $\bf B$ and $\bf M_T$?

Comment: I haven't learned about the base change matrix. But just assuming $M_T B$ should give the $T$, I do not get the matrix I described above. And I think the matrix I gave above is the correct linear transformation relative to the bases $\mathfrak{B}, \mathfrak{B'}$.